# PyQGIS: how to delete layer from TOC when attribute table is closed?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table

I'm developing plugin where I want to be able to edit non-spatial table inside the attribute table dialogue. As it seems that the only way to do so is to add this table to the TOC first, I do so. But it is pointless to keep this table inside the TOC after the editing is done and the attribute table is closed. I would like to remove table from TOC right after the attribute window is closed. Is there a way to catch the signal from the `showAttributeTable()` when it is destroyed? Or is there a way not to add table to TOC in the first place?

Here is the code that I use:

```
def qgisOpenTable(self, layer_name, schema, table, geom_column=None, subset=None):
      '''
      Opens table in QGIS attribute table window
      '''
      uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
      uri.setConnection(self.server, self.port, self.db_name, self.login, self.password)  
      uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column, subset)
      vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layer_name, "postgres")
      QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
      layer_id = vlayer.id()
      i = iface.showAttributeTable(vlayer)

      # I would like to have something like this:
      i.destroyed.connect(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer_id))
```

The only workaround that came to my mind is to remove table after some time, but this is suboptimal.

Comment: Did u solve your problem ?

Comment: @snaileater, I'm using a temporary workaround (pop a button in the QmessageBar to delete layer afterwards), though I was unable to find way to do delete table automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Rebelious,
here is what i did to solve your question (maybe not the smarter solution but working "automatically" at least ...) :

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject,QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import re

class Test():

    openedTables=[]

    def main(self):
        QApplication.instance().focusChanged.connect(self.monitor)

    def monitor(self,qa,qb):
        if qa is None:
            #print('qa=None...')
            QTimer().singleShot(100,self.timer)

        if qb is not None:
            if qb.objectName()=="mToggleEditingButton":
                tableName=re.search(r'- (\S*) ::',qb.parent().windowTitle()).group(1)
                if tableName not in self.openedTables:
                    self.openedTables.append(tableName)

    def timer(self):
        for i in self.openedTables:
                if self.checkTable(i)==False :
                    layer=QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(i)[0]
                    if not layer.hasGeometryType():
                        print('closing table : ' + str(i))
                        self.openedTables.remove(i)
                        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer.id())

    def checkTable(self,string):
        # allWidgets / topLevelWidgets
        l=QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets()
        bool=False
        for i in l:
            if i.objectName()=='QgsAttributeTableDialog':
                layerName=re.search(r'- (\S*) ::',i.windowTitle()).group(1)
                if layerName ==string:
                    bool=True
        return bool
```

The idea is to use the **focusChanged** signal of Qapplication.instance() and to record any attributeTable openings and then check table closings ...
I had to use a QTimer because when i enter the slot ("monitor") the Attribute Table loose focus but is not considered as closed yet ...

So using a timer is the only solution i found ...
There's surely a smarter way to do that ...
Hope it helps anyway !

Comment: Very interesting. But it isn't clear to me how to use it. Should I just call the `Test()` class before opening attribute table? Please rewrite code in the context of my example.

Comment: yes call the **Test()** class and then any attributeTable closing will close the table itself (as long as it isn't a geographic table, that was what u were asking i think). If u have any question ask me ...

Comment: Did it solve your question Rebelious ?